# Removing previous paths in d3.js with transition to new data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, d3.js

I currently am running a page which generates a graph with default values upon page load. The page takes the data from a TSV generated by a PHP script, modified by GET parameters.

The user can then input options, and update the graph through AJAX.

Currently the page is almost working, but it is is overlaying the new paths with the new data without removing the old paths.

The new data has the same x range and domain but different y coordinate values, sometimes with a different number of values.

Ideally I would like the old paths to fluidly transition from the old paths - how can I make this occur?

I've tried to include the relevant code below. Apologies for its poor quality, I am very new to d3.

```
...

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .defined(function(d) {
        return d.result != 0;
    })
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.result);
    });

var svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var txtDays = 7;
var txtStartDate = "01/01/2013";
var txtEndDate = "01/01/2014";
var txtInterval = 1;

requestDataURL = //removed for SO


    d3.tsv("http://localhost" + requestDataURL, function(error, data) {
        var varPolls = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
            return key !== "date";
        });

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        });

        var results = varPolls.map(function(name) {
            return {
                name: name,
                values: data.map(function(d) {
                    return {
                        date: d.date,
                        result: +d[name]
                    };
                })
            };
        });


        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
            return d.date;
        }));



        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)

        var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
            .data(results)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "group")
            .attr("data-name", function(d) {
                return d.name;
            });

        group.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                return line(d.values);
            })
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                return colors[d.name];
            });

        group.append("text")
            .datum(function(d) {
                return {
                    name: d.name,
                    value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
                };
            })
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.result) + ")";
            })
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return Math.round(d.value.result);;
            });

        d3.select(".submit")
            .attr('disabled', null);


    });

$(".submit").click(function(event) {
    var data = [];
    //SORT OUT VALIDATION


    var req = $.ajax({
        url: requestDataURL,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(response) {
            data = response;
        }
    });

    requestDataURL = //new data removed for SO

        $.when(req).done(function() {
            d3.tsv("http://localhost" + requestDataURL, function(error, data) {

                var varPolls = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
                    return key !== "date";
                });

                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                });

                var results = varPolls.map(function(name) {
                    return {
                        name: name,
                        values: data.map(function(d) {
                            return {
                                date: d.date,
                                result: +d[name]
                            };
                        })
                    };
                });


                x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                    return d.date;
                }));


                var group = svg.selectAll(".chart")
                    .data(results);

                group.exit().remove();

                group.enter().append("g");
                group.attr("class", "group")
                    .attr("data-name", function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    });

                group.append("path")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", function(d) {
                        return line(d.values);
                    })
                    .style("stroke", function(d) {
                        return colors[d.name];
                    });




                group.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .ease("linear")
                    .attr("d", group);

            });

        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not handling the enter and update selections correctly. As a rule, append operations should only happen on enter selections, not update. When you're getting new data, you have the following code:

```
group.enter().append("g");
// ...
group.append("path");
```

This will append new `path` elements to the update selection, which is what you're seeing in the graph. The proper way to handle new data would look as follows:

```
var enterSel = group.enter().append("g");
// set attributes on the g elements
enterSel.append("path"); // append path elements to the new g elements

group.select("path") // select the path elements that are present, this includes the newly appended ones
     .attr("d", function(d) { // update the d attribute
       return line(d.values);
     });
```

This code will append new elements for data items that have no corresponding elements and update the `path`s for existing elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm certainly conceptually confused about d3. I've tried this but to no avail. There are initially 4 g elements each with a path inside, the program still appends 4 g elements without the correct new paths.

Comment: Ah, it looks like your selector should be `.group` and not `.chart`. I would recommend refactoring the code to remove this duplication and avoid issues like this.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks very much! Should have seen that myself. Refactoring is the a much needed next step, just very eager to present a prototype.

Comment: One final question - how can I set a transition between the two sets of lines (and the axis, with your help I've now got them to update), rather than just jumping between the two? Do I use attrTween?

Comment: No, just add `.transition()` before setting the new attribute values/calling the axis component.